# .androidstudio folders one of each version

Tags: android

It seems that each version of android studio is putting a folder in my user directory .AndroidStudio & .AndroidStudioPreview with the version prefixed on the end. Do I need these? They are taking up over 3 gig of data.

Comment: BS on the person who voted this down. I search the internet for anything related to folders that started with .AndroidStudio and could not find anything. You suck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the set of folders for the version of Android Studio you are actively using. If you are using the Preview features, such as Android M features, I think you also need to keep the AndroidStudioPreview folder.

I have noticed this on my MacBook Pro also - I don't know why the old versions are not cleaned up when you update Android Studio. You can always look through the folders before you delete the old ones. I don't know that you need to worry about deleting the old ones though.

Comment: Thanks I assumed that was the case but thought I would ask first. I have a total of 5 folders at this point. One for each version of Android Studio as each upgrade has happened. I think I will move them to another drive and make sure things work ok before I delete them.

Comment: @user1908796 One thing to note - there is a hidden folder called `.android` that stores your virtual android devices. You do not want to delete that folder, of course. On my local drive, that folder is 22.7 GB big, so it should be pretty easy to spot if you have created more than a couple VMs.

Comment: Thank I did not delete that one. I realized that it was something different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your question was downvoted, however:

[image: Android Studio Installation Size]

If you require the Android Studio Emulator, then yes it will take 3.9 gigs for Windows atleast